# Using VS Code and It doesn't recognize ejs tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am Using Vs code and it doesn't recognize ejs output tags when they are inside an html tag like the input tag below :

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```

Before changing the default value property from **on** to **<%=item._id%>** it would actually print on, Now it does nothing !
and in the code itself i can see that it doesn't recognize it because the color doesn't change as usual.

The solutions I found were re-starting my vs-code and adding

```js
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        
        "ejs":"html"
  }
```

to my settings.json but they did not work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error(a day and a half to be precise) I used this <%- instead of <%=
and it worked. According to the documentation this <%- tag outputs unescaped value into template. See full code below:

```html
value='<%-item._id%>' 

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%-item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```

and I have a clue of how that worked but if any one can give me a comprehensive explanation that would be greatly appreciated. I would love to understand completely these how this tag works.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this question looking for a solution after experiencing a similar problem with VS Code. Specifically, VS Code flagged the EJS tags with a problem hint about having to 'escape special characters' in the following line of code:

```
<p>It's a <%= myvar %> </p>
```

While not offering to answer the OP's question, I noticed that quite a number of other users had viewed this question, and therefore my solution might be useful for others in future. My setup: Windows 10; VS Code 1.76.2; HTMLHint v1.0.4 by htmlhint.com; EJS language support v1.3.3 by DigitalBrainstem. The problem was solved by uninstalling HTMLHint and installing EJS Language Support v1.0.6, by Leon Si.